# In Medieval or early Renaissance times, how could England close its ports to prevent escape?

Tags: middle-ages, england, border

From time to time I read that in Medieval or early Renaissance times the King/Queen/Privy Council "closed the ports" to prevent someone escaping England.  How could this be done effectively?

There was no standard way to identify people (other than bringing them in front of people who knew them) and a verbal description would usually be imprecise. (Well, unless you were a 6'10" man missing his left eye.) Further, port officials were normally focussed on collecting duties -- there was nothing like an airside security zone in which everyone had been positively vetted.

So how did this work? How did, say, Elizabeth's Privy Council tell the ports of England to prevent wanted Jesuit Fr. Fugitive from boarding a ship for the continent? And how did they implement it? Was there an effective mechanism for the government providing export passports which were always needed to board ship? (This seems unlikely.)

I have done web searches and checked Wikipedia, but found nothing on topic. (Lots on closing ports on computer systems!) I do find reference to occasional Elizabethan letters from the Q/PC directing the Crown's servants to expedite so-and-so on some mission, but they appears to be extraordinary and not relevant.

I limit the question to England because it looks even harder to close land borders effectively back then.

Added: @Jan commented that '"closing the port" means that no ship is allowed to leave the port.' I considered this, but it seems like a hopelessly draconian measure to prevent one person from leaving. If thus closing the ports was effective and the fugitive captured, it would probably still take weeks to effect the capture, and many times he would not ever be captured (e.g., fled to the fens to hide and died; successfully escaped; went to ground in a friendly manor). How long would the PC have to wait for a capture before giving up? Additionally, even if the fugitive is captured, it might take weeks for word of a capture to read London and a re-opening order to be received at the ports. Closing all trade for a month or sometimes for many months seems impractical.

Comment: I was always assuming "closing the port" means that no ship is allowed to leave the port. That would be relatively easy to implement (or at least to confirm) for port officials.

Comment: Good point.  Added material to question why I think this is not valid.

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is, but Elizabeth I (at least) had a very extensive and efficient network of spies and informants, so tracking an individual (say RC priest ) might not have been that difficult?

Comment: @Mark Olson Re. the added material: Do you have any references to ports being "closed" for a prolonged time? One could just do this as an emergency measure until less drastic measures can be implemented E.g. until leaflets about the fugitive can be distributed or the harbour authorities can be instructed in more detail.

Comment: Perhaps the port was closed to people of a certain class/status?  "During the late 1500s, Queen Elizabeth I passed a series of strict laws relating to dress codes. The laws ensured that people across the social spectrum dressed according to their rank and class"  https://www.bl.uk/learning/timeline/item126628.html

Comment: @Jan  That's part of my point.  I see *no* evidence of this (in regard to individual g\fugitives, as opposed to enemy trade), yet it's hard to see how a short closure would have been effective. It's all part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Mark Olson A short closure gives the authorities time. E.g. to sort out *whom exactly* they are searching for. Or to muster more people for checking on outgoing travel. It also heightens awareness that something important is going on.

Comment: I actually think that similar things still happen today, or at at least *can happen*. E.g. police sometimes erect *temporary* checkpoints on major roads after certain crimes. If the criminal just stays put, the police will not catch him, but that does not mean such checkpoints are useless.